# "Object has been destroyed" when sending through IPC

Tags: javascript, typescript, electron

I want my electron front-end to send data given by user to back-end through IPC, and backend to process data, but to also notify front-end about the progress, so I read in docs that to send stuff I should use `win.webContents.send()` so I used it, but on line where it's used it throws `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Object has been destroyed`.

```js
let win: BrowserWindow

app.on('ready', () => {
  win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 600, height: 400 })

  win.loadFile(`/${__dirname}/gui.html`)
})

let sc: Screenshooter

ipcMain.on(
  'fire',
  async (
    event: { sender: { send: (channnel: string, msg: string) => void } },
    e: { url: string; args: object; pauseBefore: boolean }
  ) => {
    sc = new Screenshooter(e.url, e.args)
    event.sender.send('status', 'preparing')

    await sc.prepare().catch(errorExit)

    win.webContents.send('status', 'ready') // UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Object has been destroyed

    // ...
    // more sending contents and operating on object

    }
  }
)

function errorExit(e: any) {
  console.error(e)
  dialog.showErrorBox('Error', 'Error: ' + e)
  process.exit(1)
}
```

Why is `win.webContents.send` throwing en error and how can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting error in `win.webContents.send` which leads to promise rejection and is not handled by your code. 
Wrap the code within `try catch` block.

```
// your code

ipcMain.on(
  'fire',
  async(...Params...) => {
    try {
      sc = new Screenshooter(e.url, e.args);
      event.sender.send('status', 'preparing');
      await sc.prepare();
      await win.webContents.send('status', 'ready');
    } catch(e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
)
```

The error says that your `win` object no longer exist, it has been destroyed. The `win` is reference to new window, it seems like you are closing the window (leads to destroy of `win` object), but later it is being referenced in `ipcMain`and it could not find the `win` object.

Comment: Yeah I know that it throws an error, but my question is why. The error it gives me is very non descriptive and I don't know what causes it

Comment: I don't close the window, I even console.logged `win`:
```{ win:
   BrowserWindow {
     setBounds: [Function],
     _events:
      { blur: [Function],
        focus: [Function],
        show: [Function: visibilityChanged],
        hide: [Function: visibilityChanged],
        minimize: [Function: visibilityChanged],
        maximize: [Function: visibilityChanged],
        restore: [Function: visibilityChanged] },
     _eventsCount: 7,
     devToolsWebContents: [Getter] } }
``` 
it seems like it still exists

Comment: @FilipKrawczyk The window variable may exist, but the actual window pointed to by BrowserWindow may not. Log `win.isDestroyed()` instead